# Structuring Cassandra Database Reads in Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, generics

I have a repo that contains a number of Spark programs. The programs frequently read from various Cassandra tables. To facilitate reading from the tables, I've added companion objects to the case classes representing the data types in each of the tables with methods to simplify retrieval.

```
case class Home(
                 user_id: String,
                 home_id: String,
                 confirmed: Boolean,
                 joined_home_utc: Timestamp
               )

object Home extends CassandraReadable[Home.Partition, Home] {
  case class Partition(user_id: String)

  def readFromCassandra(session: SparkSession, partitions: Option[Dataset[Partition]] = Option.empty): Dataset[Home] = {
    import session.implicits._
    import com.datastax.spark.connector._

    var homes = session
      .read
      .cassandraFormat("homes", "default", pushdownEnable = true)
      .load
      .directJoin(AlwaysOn)
      .as[Home]

    if (partitions.isDefined) {
      val partitionDs = partitions.get
      homes = partitionDs.joinWith(homes, partitionDs("user_id") === homes("user_id"))
        .map(_._2)
    }

    homes
  }
}
```

To allow for incremental ingestion, we typically only read a subset of the table's partitions at once. Since this is the case for nearly all of the tables, I've created a trait which outlines the structure of the retrieval methods.

```
trait CassandraReadable[PartitionType, ResultType] {
  def readFromCassandra(session: SparkSession, partitions: Option[Dataset[PartitionType]]=Option.empty): Dataset[ResultType]
}
```

I define the case class representing a table's partitions within the companion object, but I'm now getting a circular dependency error when implementing the trait. Is there a better way I should be going about this? I believe moving the partition to another file would resolve the circular dependency issue, but I was hoping to keep information relevant to the table all within one file, as the `Partition` class is never really used outside of the context of interaction with the table. Scala is not my primary language so I may be totally off-base with design philosophy here. Any help is appreciated, thanks!